# RHLE8 conflicts to install mysql-community-server

Tags: mysql, redhat

I try to install mysql on my Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 with the command :

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

and I have this message:

> Error: Transaction test error:
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/authentication_fido_client.so from
> install of mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> conflicts with file from package
> mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/authentication_kerberos_client.so from
> install of mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> conflicts with file from package
> mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/authentication_ldap_sasl_client.so from
> install of mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> conflicts with file from package
> mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/authentication_oci_client.so from install
> of mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> conflicts with file from package
> mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/private/libfido2.so.1.5.0 from install of
> mysql-cluster-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts
> with file from package
> mysql-community-client-plugins-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.21.2.28 conflicts between
> attempted installs of mysql-community-libs-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-libs-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysql conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysql_config_editor conflicts between attempted installs
> of mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysql_migrate_keyring conflicts between attempted
> installs of mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysqladmin conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysqlbinlog conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysqlcheck conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysqldump conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysqlimport conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysqlpump conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysqlshow conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysqlslap conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-cluster-community-client-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/ibd2sdi conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/innochecksum conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/lz4_decompress conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/my_print_defaults conflicts between attempted installs
> of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/myisam_ftdump conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/myisamchk conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/myisamlog conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/myisampack conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation conflicts between attempted
> installs of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysql_ssl_rsa_setup conflicts between attempted installs
> of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql conflicts between attempted installs
> of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/perror conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/bin/zlib_decompress conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/adt_null.so conflicts between attempted
> installs of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/auth_socket.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_audit_api_message_emit.so
> conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_keyring_file.so conflicts
> between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_log_filter_dragnet.so conflicts
> between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_log_sink_json.so conflicts
> between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_log_sink_syseventlog.so
> conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_mysqlbackup.so conflicts
> between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_query_attributes.so conflicts
> between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_reference_cache.so conflicts
> between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/component_validate_password.so conflicts
> between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/connection_control.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/ddl_rewriter.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/group_replication.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/ha_example.so conflicts between attempted
> installs of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/ha_mock.so conflicts between attempted
> installs of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/innodb_engine.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/keyring_file.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/keyring_udf.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/libmemcached.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/libpluginmecab.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/locking_service.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/mypluglib.so conflicts between attempted
> installs of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/mysql_clone.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/mysql_no_login.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/rewrite_example.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/rewriter.so conflicts between attempted
> installs of mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/semisync_master.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/semisync_replica.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/semisync_slave.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/semisync_source.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/validate_password.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/version_token.so conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/private/libprotobuf-lite.so.3.11.4 conflicts
> between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/lib64/mysql/private/libprotobuf.so.3.11.4 conflicts between
> attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64
> file /usr/sbin/mysqld conflicts between attempted installs of
> mysql-cluster-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64 and
> mysql-community-server-8.0.28-1.el8.x86_64

I don't understand the message, if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've already got the community cluster server installed.  Try this: `yum list installed | grep mysql-community-server`

If it's installed you can `yum remove mysql-community-server` and then attempt the cluster install.